# How does WCF take care of multiple client calls to the server?

Tags: multithreading, wcf

Want to get a clear understanding of how WCF works.
Lets say a WCF service has exposed a function A.
Now the client creates 5 threads, and in each one of them calls the function A with different parameters.

I assume this should happen - a new instance of function A would get created for every thread call to that function. Could some one confirm this.
I have written a POC which is not doing this, its giving inconsistent results.

Answer (score 5):

This depends on your service configuration via the ServiceBehavior attribute on the class implementing your service contract:

```
[ServiceBehavior(
    InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession, 
    ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
```

With the parameter `InstanceContextMode` you tell WCF how you want to host your service:

- **Single**: One instance of your service class will be created which receives all service calls
- **PerSession**: For each connecting client a new instance will be created
- **PerCall** (default): For each call of every client a new instance will be created

The next thing is synchronisation, when one host object receives parallel operation calls. You can control the behavior with the `ConcurrencyMode` parameter:

- **Single** (Default): WCF serialises all operations, so your service instance is executing exactly one or no operation call at a time.
- **Reentrant**: WCF delegates all operation calls to your service instance directly, but synchronises calls to another WCF service inside a service operation (rarely used i think).
- **Multiple**: WCF delegates all operation calls to your service instances directly without synchronization. You have to worry about synchronisation yourself.

Comment: Mind you: ConcurrencyMode.Multiple causes everything to be multi-threaded and thus much harder and trickier to program. It also only really has any tangible benefits in the InstanceContextMode.Single (singleton) case. Avoid this if ever possible - it's just unnecessarily complicated and doesn't yield any perf improvement in per-call or per-session

Comment: Yes, so i wrote you are responsible for synchronisation. But i think it highly depends on your use case which option is optimal. For the beginning its definitly better to go with ConcurrencyMode.Single

Answer (score 1):

The default is for a new instance of your wcf service to be created per call, this is documented e.g. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx)

Comment: Exactly - the "per-call" model - each call gets a new service class instance - is the preferred and default instancing model. Great MSDN Magazine article to illustrate that

Comment: The default is actually PerSession. It used to be PerCall in CTP versions back in 2006 but was changed before release. If the binding does not support sessions however (e.g. BasicHttpBinding), it will behave as per call.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing like a new instance of function. It'd be rather instance of class.

You can configure how your Service should behave by changing proper meta attribute.

You can make your service implementation instantiated per call. It can also work as singleton (one and only service instance for all calls).

[Here you can find information on creating singleton WCF service](http://codeidol.com/csharp/wcf/Instance-Management/Singleton-Service/)

[And here there is a lot more about WCF services](http://codeidol.com/csharp/wcf/Instance-Management/)